# Intuition behind twoway fixed effects

Tags: econometrics, fixed-effects-model

Let us assume we have the following linear regression model:
$$
w_{it}=\alpha_i+v_t+\varepsilon_{it}
$$
where $w_{it}$ represents wage of an individual $i$ at time $t,$ $\alpha_i$ is an individual fixed effect and $v_t$ is a year fixed effect. Is there a closed form expression for $\hat{\alpha}_i^\text{OLS}$?
In the simple case with no year effects, $\alpha_i$ could be thought of as conditional mean of wages, but the presence of year effects makes such an interpretation complicated. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Two way ANOVA could be a place to start. Generally the time effect accounts for events that affect all individuals at a given point in time, say, lower earnings after the financial crisis.

Answer (score 1):

In brief, the answer is yes...there is a closed form solution.   Without using matrix notation, the answer is
$$\hat{\beta}_\alpha = \frac{\left(SS_\upsilon\right)\left(SS_{\alpha w}\right)-\left(SS_{\alpha\upsilon}\right)\left(SS_{\upsilon w}\right)}{\left(SS_\alpha\right)\left(SS_\upsilon\right)-\left(SS_{\alpha\upsilon}\right)^2}$$
where $SS_x = \sum x_i^2 - \frac{1}{n}\left(\sum x_i\right)^2$ and $SS_{xy} = \sum xy - \frac{1}{n}\left(\sum x\right)\left(\sum y\right)$.

This is the (by-hand) computational solution for the multiple regression partial slope for $\alpha$ (with a 2-independent predictor model).   Note, this equation doesn’t reveal the process of the solution.   However, in this case, I’m not certain walking through the solution would garner the intuition you are looking for here.

With a little bit of algebra, we can rewrite this formula (because this is the 2-independent variable MR model) as
$$\hat{\beta}_\alpha = \frac{r_{\alpha w} - r_{\alpha \upsilon}r_{w \upsilon}}{1-r_{\alpha\upsilon}^2} \frac{s_w}{s_\alpha}$$
where $r_{xy}$ is the correlation between $x$ and $y$ and $s_x$ is the standard deviation of $x$.

So, for the intuition, we can rewrite the partial slope equation a bit.   We will use the following relationships:

1. the standardized partial slope and the partial slope: $$\beta_x = \beta_x^\star \left(\frac{s_y}{s_x}\right)$$
2. the standardized partial slope and the semi-partial correlation: $${}_\text{sp}r_{xy(z)} = \beta_x^\star \sqrt{1-R_{xz}^2}$$ where $x$ and $z$ are the two independent variables in the MR model.  (The semi-partial here is between $x$ and $y$ after partialing out the influence of $z$ from $y$.)

So, our formula for the partial slope can be written as
$$\hat{\beta}_\alpha = {}_\text{sp}r_{\alpha w (\upsilon)} · \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-r_{\alpha\upsilon}^2}}\right) · \left(\frac{s_w}{s_\alpha}\right)$$
These three factors do indeed have concrete interpretations.

1. The first factor is the relationship between $\alpha$ and $w$, after controlling for the influence of $\upsilon$ (the semi-partial correlation).
2. The second factor is a scaling factor for the amount of information that is “shared” between $\alpha$ and $\upsilon$ (note, if there is no correlation, then this term is 1).
3. The final factor is just the scaling factor to take the standardized partial slope back to the units of the model.

Hope this helps...happy to clarify as needed.